# How can I support API 16 but still have Leanback?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-build, android-tv, leanback

I made my game work on Android TV, it required `Leanback library`, which wants `minSdkVersion` to be 17. I must support API 16 too. What can I do?

When building, I get an error this suggestion:

`Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback" to force usage`

What exactly does it do? Does it actually make my app still support API 16? What am I losing?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed information [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker).

Here is what it says:

> tools:overrideLibrary marker
>
> A special marker that can only be used with uses-sdk declaration to
>   override importing a library which minimum SDK version is more recent
>   than that application's minimum SDK version. Without such a marker,
>   the manifest merger will fail. The marker **will allow users to select
>   which libraries can be imported ignoring the minimum SDK version**.

And you need to do the following: In the main android manifest :

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="2"
          tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v17.leanback"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gintas_ well, I guess Leanback v17 library supports all API levels starting from 17, that means it was tested starting from api level 17. Some features of the library can still work on api level 16 and less, but you need to test your app on a device using api level 16 or less just to make sure.